# How to connect to MySQL running on XAMPP through WSL terminal

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xampp, flask

MySQL is running on XAMPP and working fine. I am trying to connect to it through the Windows Subsystem for Linux running a Flask app using flask-msqldb.
But when I run the Flask app and try to make a connection (`mysql.connection.cursor()`) the following error ensues:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Is it even possible to make them connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay just did some digging around and found this helped:

- Instead of 'localhost' use the IP address instead Eg:`app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'` apparently, clients have some internal aliasing done which results in conflicts. Read:[source](https://serverfault.com/a/337844)
- Add the Flask config setting `app.config['MYSQL_UNIX_SOCKET'] = 'TCP'` which specifies that the connection is remote.